# Data loss between conversion

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

Why is it that I loose data between the conversions below even though both types take up the same amount of space?  If the conversion was done bitwise, it should be true that `x = z` unless data is being stripped during the conversion, right?  Is there a way to do the two conversions without losing data (i.e. so that `x = z`)?

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    double   x = 5.5;
    uint64_t y = static_cast<uint64_t>(x);
    double   z = static_cast<double>(y) // Desire : z = 5.5;

    printf("Size of double: %lu\nSize of uint64_t: %lu\n", sizeof(double), sizeof(uint64_t));
    printf("%f\n%lu\n%f\n", x, y, z);
}
```

Results:

```
Size of double: 8
Size of uint64_t: 8
5.500000
5
5.000000
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The conversion is not bitwise.

The first conversion *converts* the value to an unsigned integer:

```
uint64_t y = static_cast<uint64_t>(x);  // y == 5
```

The second takes that integer, and *converts* it to a double of the same value

```
double   z = static_cast<double>(y) // Convert 5 to 5.0
```

The fact that the types use the same amount of memory is irrelevant, as the `static_cast` changes the type.  You would see the same behavior if you converted to then from an `uint32_t`, as well.  It does not merely perform a bitwise conversion.

If you want to perform a bitwise conversion, you could do this via pointer manipulation:

```
double   x = 5.5;
uint64_t y = *((uint64_t*)&x);  // Will effectively be a "garbage" value
double   z = *((double*)(&y)); // Will be 5.5
```

Comment: Makes sense.  Then is there a built-in way to do a bitwise conversion of the types?  Or do I have to roll my own converter to do such a thing?

Comment: @AlexBrooks No, there isn't.  You could use pointers to handle this, though.

Comment: Okay, perfect.  Could you provide an example of how to do the conversion with pointers so I know I'm on the right track?

Comment: Whenever I try the conversion with pointers, I receive errors stating I am doing invalid casts (`invalid static_cast from type double* to type uint64_t* {aka long unsigned int*}` and `invalid static_cast from type uint64_t* {aka long unsigned int*} to type double*`)

Comment: @AlexBrooks: Why do you want to do a bitwise conversion? That is the interesting question. You might be barking at the wrong tree here...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas With the library I'm using, one of my functions is required to have a return type of uint64_t for the results, yet my data are doubles.  Once the function is done computing and the value is returned, I need the data to be a double so that the return value reflects the actual results of the function.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @AlexBrooks: It makes sense. There is a design issue and instead of trying to fix it you want to hammer in a hack. If you are implementing an interface that returns `uint64_t` and you return a bit pattern that represents a `double` users are probably going to be confused: Why `getCurrentValue()` return a value that is completely unrelated to the *current value* (pick your choice of function name). BTW, instead of the suggested reinterpret casts, you should use `memcpy` from `double` to `int64_t` and back... or better yet, don't do this at all.

Comment: Reed, your suggested solution is undefined behavior as you are breaking the strict aliasing rule. The compiler is free to reorder the last two lines in your code as the pointers refer to unrelated types. This is not theoretical, I have suffered debugging a process that was producing the wrong output for this exact reason.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas To put more context to my need for the conversion, I'm working with the qthreads library (http://www.cs.sandia.gov/qthreads/) for doing task-based parallelism.  In order to create a thread and do work on it, you must call the function qthread_fork(...) which takes three arguments: a function of the form `aligned_t function(void *arg)` (where `aligned_t` is defined as `uint64_t`), a pointer to the arguments for the given function (`void *arg`), and a pointer to the location where the results of the function will be placed (`aligned_t *ret`).  The work

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas reinterpret_cast should be safe, right?  (Given that it's only being converted back to the original type or to/from integers before being used...)

Comment: I want the threads to do is simply a numerical estimation of an integral.  In order to do that, you need to be working with doubles.  Therefore I need the conversion so that casting my results to `uint64_t` types don't clobber my results.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: The problem is not with the casts of the pointers, but with the read/write to the pointed memory. The compiler can assume (the standard allows it to assume) that a pointer to `double` and a pointer to `int64_t` never alias the same memory, so for the purpose of the *as-if* rule the instructions that write and read the memory location can be reordered. I.e. the compiler is allowed to generate this code: `double x,z; uint64_t y; x = 5.5; z = *((double*)(&y)); y = *((uint64_t*)(&x));`, which will interpret uninitialized `y` memory into `z`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes, but given the OP's scenario, there's a lot happening in between (he's passing into/out of a 3rd party API), so while my example code will not work (since it's sequential), that could never happen, right?  [y is fed into an API, and then read back out later for conversion to z, from my understanding]

Comment: @ReedCopsey There is one place where I do the two conversions in the same function: `double result = *((double*)&lresult) + *((double*)&rresult); return *((aligned_t*)&result);` (lresult and rresult are return values (`uint64_t`) of calls to the aforementioned `function`).  Would this cause an issue in terms of the compiler reordering?  The reason I did the conversion back to double for the addition is because I experienced "undefined behavior" when I left the results as `uint64_t`